# npm , yarn, package.json issue

Tags: json, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

When I try to run `npm start`, this occurs. Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\john\Desktop\final project\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\john\Desktop\final project\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-
29T09_09_03_125Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a package.json file ?
is the start script defined in the package.json ?
Also i guess you are trying to start a react application on your localhost.

use create-react-app to create the app which pre-installs some packages plus the scripts you'll need to run and test.

use `npm install -g create-react-app`

OR

go into your package.json file look at the scripts object which should look like this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

If you don't have a start script defined, then go ahead and define it.

I hope this helps

Comment: it's all fine but it is not still working ;(
the package json is properly arranged and i also started a new app using npm install -g create-react-app

sir, is there are any way to completely uninstall and then make it work

Comment: could you post your package.json file, also to completely uninstall use a the super admin. so `sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app` @JohnMellow . You can also manually check the directory where it was installed and completely remove the folder